Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'google') in passport
import { bind, BindingScope, inject, service } from '@loopback/core'
import { AnyObject } from '@loopback/repository'
import { HttpErrors } from '@loopback/rest'
import { UserProfile } from '@loopback/security'
import { Request, Response } from 'express'
import { isNil } from 'lodash'
import { authenticate, PassportStatic, use } from 'passport'
import { AuthenticateOptionsGoogle, Profile, Strategy, VerifyCallback } from 'passport-google-oauth20'
import { EnvironmentConfig } from '../../config'
import { EnvironmentBinding } from '../../keys'
import { CreateUserPayload } from '../../typings/igamio'
import { generatePassword } from '../../utils'
import { UserService } from '../user.service'

@bind({ scope: BindingScope.SINGLETON })
export class GooglePassportService {
  constructor(@service(UserService) private readonly userService: UserService,
    @inject(EnvironmentBinding) private readonly env: EnvironmentConfig
  ) { }

  authenticate(
    request: Request,
    response?: Response,
    options: AuthenticateOptionsGoogle = {
      session: false,
      scope: [
        'profile',
        'email',
        'openid',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.birthday.read',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.gender.read',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.phonenumbers.read'
      ]
    },
    callback?: (error: Error | null, user: UserProfile | null) => void
  ): PassportStatic {
    return authenticate('google', options, callback)(request, response?.status(201))
  }

  initialize(): PassportStatic {
    const config = this.env.configGoogleOauth2Strategy
    return use(new Strategy(config,
      async (accessToken: string, refreshToken: string, profile: Profile,
        done: VerifyCallback) => this.verify(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done)
    )
    )
  }

  async verify(accessToken: string, refreshToken: string, profile: Profile, done: VerifyCallback): Promise<void> {
    try {
      const data = this.formatUserData(profile._json)
      const user = await this.userService.insertPassportUser(data)
      return done(null, { ...user, accessToken, refreshToken })
    } catch (error) {
      return done(error as Error)
    }
  }

I am using facebook also
I am getting below error
Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'google') in passport
my vesrion

"@types/passport-google-oauth20": "2.0.8",
"passport": "0.4.1",,
"passport-google-oauth20": "2.0.0",
also I have tryed with


"@types/passport-google-oauth20": "2.0.14",
"passport": "0.7.0",,
"passport-google-oauth20": "2.0.0",

Node js version
v20.11.1
npm version
10.2.4
geeting same error
geeting error line
Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'google') in passport

node_modules/passport/lib/authenticator.js:58:26

When I made change like
import passport from 'passport'
passport.use
passport.authenticate
in this case facebook is working fine But in google auth geeting below error





error TypeError: next is not a function
at strategy.error (/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:361:9)
at OAuth2Strategy.authenticate (/node_modules/passport-oauth2/lib/strategy.js:300:21)
at attempt (/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:366:16)





